# Does memory get deallocated once the pointer goes out of scope?

Tags: fortran90

Suppose I have this subroutine:

```
subroutine a () 
  integer, pointer :: b 
  allocate(b) 
end subroutine a
```

The variable `b` is on the subroutine's stack and will therefore get destroyed once the program returns from the subroutine. But what about the target it was pointing to? As far as I can tell from reading the F90 standard, the target is *not* deallocated, but I can't find a definite statement saying that explicitly.

Comment: Unless the language is defined to perform garbage collection, it would be wrong for it to deallocate it. You might have assigned the pointer to a global variable.

Comment: The reason I was asking is that according to my reading of the standard, a variable with the `allocatable` attribute does get deallocated upon leaving scope. In practice though variables with either `pointer` or `allocatable` attributes behave otherwise identically, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **NO**.  You are responsible to call `deallocate(b)` the same way you are responsible to call `allocate(b(100))` in the first place.